# how to convert multiple python to exe file with one data file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I have to convert multiple python script and one json file to an exe file, with only on executable. Please post an example if possible.

Comment: Check out pyinstaller, works like a charm

Comment: Any solution for this, I am also looking answer for this

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller has an option called `--onefile`

See the document here: http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html

Comment: how do i include my data file i.e json file to it?

Comment: If the data in the json file doesn't change from outside the program, you can store it inside the code with a dict. If it needs to be outside so that you can change the value in json, then read the file from the program. Every time you restart the program, you will read the new value from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a module named cx_Freeze.
Read the documentation.
Refer the tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQsGuBfC5dA&list=PLT_6xP6jAq8jGg4QgDHqOwxHLy-L66mqU&index=47
It has a detailed explanation.

Comment: Cx_Freeze does not create single file exe unfortunately.

Comment: exactly, what should i go for then.